# how to compile mlton under mac osx yosemite?

Tags: osx-yosemite

I am trying to compile mlton on my mac osx yosemite laptop in preparation to compile and run ur/web. However, the compile does not complete but essentially nothing is indicative of the source of the problem. So I am wondering whether others have had successs running yosemite?

Answer (score 1):

I just got MLton to compile on the Mac. I used the following steps:

0. Download and install Homebrew

1. Download and install Gnump (`./configure; make install`)
2. `brew install smlnj`
3. `make smlnj-mlton`
4. `make` (took a really long time to compile!)
5. `make install`

Answer (score 0):

Brew install mlton

*make takes 10 min - 15 min